# Convert this prototype hash to plain javascript/jquery?

Tags: jquery, hash, prototypejs

I need to get rid of prototype from a site so I need to convert this:

```
var moduleCodeHash = new Hash();
moduleCodeHash.set('SHIPMANAGER','SHIPMENTFILTER');
moduleCodeHash.set('TRAFFICMGR','TRAFFICMGRFILTER');
moduleCodeHash.set('SHIPBIDMONITOR','BIDFILTER');

moduleCodeHash.get(selectedValue);
```

to plain js or jquery

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006984/how-to-create-hash-object-array-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not doing anything fancy with it then don't make it fancy, use an ordinary object.

```js
var moduleCodeHash = {};
moduleCodeHash['SHIPMANAGER']    = 'SHIPMENTFILTER';
moduleCodeHash['TRAFFICMGR']     = 'TRAFFICMGRFILTER';
moduleCodeHash['SHIPBIDMONITOR'] = 'BIDFILTER';

moduleCodeHash[selectedValue]; // get selectedValue
```