# How to create a hashed email in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, hash

I'm needing to hash an email in jQuery for use with [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/).

So:

```
http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/user@email.com
```

will turn into:

```
http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50
```

I'm able to get the email from Python/Mako and pass it on into my jQuery class.

```
var gravatar_placeholder = $('#modal-vcard .vcard_profile_pic img').prop('src');
var substr = gravatar_placeholder.split('__gravatar__').join(their_email);
```

The user's email is `their_email` and I need to hash in jquery/javascript before the 2nd line above so it will then generate the [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/).

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006984/how-to-create-hash-object-array-using-jquery) here, but wasn't able to get it to work in my situation.

Any tips? How would you have approached this?

Comment: It would probably be better to do this in python before you send it to jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several hash algorithms and I am not sure which one you want to use but MD5 is a quite popular hash algorithm.

For instance, `someemail@test.com` hashed in MD5 is `9cb0cbcda88377b1e1d66e8d7f01cbae`.

https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5

Comment: Ah cool thanks! http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-MD5/ I just learned about hashing today :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another example which uses the crypto library

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js"></script>
<script>
var hash = CryptoJS.MD5("name@test.com");
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + hash;
document.body.appendChild(img);
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome this was super easy :)