# Meteor, Javascript to create Hash Key for Gravatar

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, meteor, gravatar

I read some postings about creating hash keys in jQuery.

[How to create a hashed email in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391903/how-to-create-a-hashed-email-in-jquery)

So I did this in my meteor to get the Gravatar profile photo from github email address. But it is not working. I think Hash Key is produced correctly but I am not sure how to do this in Meteor.

Following is my trying.
in HTML file

```
      <template name="messages">
         {{#each messages}}
       <strong>{{name}}</strong> : {{message}}<br>
         {{/each}}
         <img src=img_add/>
      </template>
```

in Javascript file

```
 var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(git_email);
 var img_add = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + hash;
```

This produces a broken link.

How do I insert profile Gravatar photo in meteor, given email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a helper just like in the hello world example.

Your client side javascript:

```
Template.messages.img_add = function() {
    var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(git_email);
    return img_add = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + hash;
}
```

Your template:

```
 <img src={{img_add}}/>
```

Or if you want to use it in the `{{#each }}` loop, use this slight modification & make sure your `{{img_add}}` helper is within the `{{#each }}` block. I'm not too sure how your doing the variables, but as long as the `git_email` is in each of your documents you're looping over.

```
Template.messages.img_add = function() {
    var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(this.git_email);
    return img_add = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + hash;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried services.github.email / 
this.services.github.email / 
Meteor.users.services.github.email  to define git_email but none of them works.

Comment: You also have to publish the fields, `services` is not available by default to the client because it contains sensitive info sometimes (access token) see the meteor docs under publish, they have an example specifically with the users data